# Project Reactor verification of conditions

Tags: java, project-reactor

tell me how to work with conditions in Reactive.

I have simple DTO **SignInRequest** and **signIn** method.

```
public class SignInRequest {

  private String userName;
  private String password;
}

public Mono<SignInResponse> signIn(SignInRequest signInRequest) {
    boolean isValid = StringUtils.isEmailValid(signInRequest.getUserName());
    return userService.findByEmail(signInRequest.getUserName())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found [email: " + signInRequest.getEmail() + "]")))
        .filter(user -> passwordService.validatePassword(user.getPassword(), signInRequest.getPassword()))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadRequestException("Wrong email or password")))
        .flatMap(this::generateTokens);
}
```

How to correctly implement the following logic.

If `isValid == true` then call the **findByEmail** method. Otherwise, call **findByUsername**

Comment: As a side note, creating exception objects is very expensive because of filling in stack traces. You should use lambdas in pipelines like these; wrapping in `Mono.defer` will take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think the most readable implementation would be the following:

```
public Mono<SignInResponse> signIn(SignInRequest signInRequest) {
    return Mono
            .fromSupplier(() -> StringUtils.isEmailValid(signInRequest.getUserName()))
            .flatMap(isValid ->
                    isValid ? userService.findByEmail(signInRequest.getUserName())
                            : userService.findByUsername(signInRequest.getUserName())
            )
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadRequestException("Wrong email or password")))
            .flatMap(this::generateTokens);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no if-else in the reactor chain  but we could make it work like this.

```
Mono.fromSupplier(() -> StringUtils.isEmailValid(signInRequest.getUserName()))
    .filter(o -> o)
    .flatMap(o -> userService.findByEmail(signInRequest.getUserName()))
    .switchIfEmpty(userService.findByUsername(signInRequest.getUserName()))
    ...
```